# Can I remove my MBP SSD and install it into my PC?

Tags: macos, mac, boot, ssd

I have a dying MBP due to the Radeongate issue. I just built myself a new PC. It is Intel based. Can I remove the SSD from my MBP and install it into an SSD bay on my PC and then boot into OS X?

Thanks!

Comment: You can format the drive and use it.  You won't be able to boot into OS X on anything except Apple hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. OS X requires Apple hardware. You could look at running a [hackintosh](http://www.hackintosh.com/), though the legality is dubious and it'll be a lot more work than simply putting the SSD into a PC, if it's possible at all on your new hardware.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this is very helpful. I will take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it since hardware structure of Mac is different of that of PC. You can format it to FAT/NTFS and use it on PC. But formatting will erase all content on it. Best is to make its backup, format and use for PC.